# Grab URL through Java/Actionscript/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

this is what I'm looking to do.

I have an ActionScript 3.0/Java bridge, basically the SWF (front end) sends commands to the Java through RTMP and the Java processes it.

What I want to do is a URL check to check if the SWF that's sending commands to the Java is being ran on a specific URL, if the URL doesn't match what I put in the if statement then the function won't continue.

How am I supposed to do such a thing?

Comment: Please provide code that you've tried so that we can better assist you.

Comment: I haven't tried anything to be honest lol, I don't know where to start, just need a good idea to incorporate that system

Comment: You can try googling for articles about this topic. Otherwise it needs an mini-essay from various research. Using logic, well Java can't check SWF location cos it only sees the RTMP server. So either you research if possible for RTMP server to detect location / IP of incoming data, or you get the SWF itself to check before even connecting to RTMP server. For that you can use `stage.loaderInfo.url;` on a `String` object, then check if that updated string contains example "www.allowedsite.com" and if true then do connection...

Comment: Hi @VC.One first I'd like to thank you for actually providing help and not just disliking this.

Comment: And second, yea of course, Java can't see the URL, so I was thinking of connecting JavaScript to Java, think that'd work? I want it so it'd fetch the URL of the user loading the SWF, not just the URL it's hosted on (the JavaScript). Or checking the URL with the SWF and sending it to the Java since I have the bridge setup already, I don't need code here really, just need the concept. And I don't know what to search on Google for since (as you can see) I'm not very good with wording my problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working in a loaded SWF you can use loaderInfo:

```
trace(this.loaderInfo.url);
```

If not you can check the external interface (if you're SWF is embedded in an HTML)

```
if (ExternalInterface.available == true){
    if (ExternalInterface.call('document.location.href.toString') != null){
        trace(  ExternalInterface.call('document.location.href.toString')); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I use a combination of loaderInfo, parts of the Capabilities object and the outbound useragent/referrer url to valid where the swf is run.